# Browserify | dotenv variable value 'undefined' in the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I would like to understand why when inspecting the variable value in the browser it shows as 'undefined'

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const apiKey = process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY;
console.log('API key: ' + apiKey);
```

```html
<script src="js/api_key_bundle.js" type="module"></script>
```

When I run in vscode locally, it returns the api key correctly, so, it is not a dotenv issue.

After I run the command:

```
browserify apiKey.js -o api_key_bundle.js
```

Then I go to the console and the value is: 'undefined'

[image]

All that I need is to use the api key in the index.html file:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + apiKey + '&callback=initMap';
script.defer = true;
script.async = true;
```

Which works if I hard code the apiKey variable with a key value...

Is any one able to help please?

Answer (score -1):

As a feedback, I did not find a solution for this so I've decided to use another approach without browserify/js...